# Reduce output from three commands to one line

Tags: powershell, output, line

I have this script:

```
$counterWS = "\Process(powershell)\Working Set"
$counterWSPe = "\Process(powershell)\Working Set Peak" 
$counterWSPr = "\Process(powershell)\Working Set - Private"

$dataWS = Get-Counter -Counter $counterWS
$dataWSPe = Get-Counter -Counter $counterWSPe
$dataWSPr = Get-Counter -Counter $counterWSPr

$dataWS.countersamples | Format-Table Timestamp,@{Name='WorkingSet';Expression={($_.CookedValue/1KB)}},WorkingSetPeak,WorkingSetPrivate -Auto | findstr Timestamp
$dataWS.countersamples | Format-Table Timestamp,@{Name='WorkingSet';Expression={($_.CookedValue/1KB)}},WorkingSetPeak,WorkingSetPrivate -Auto | findstr [-]

while ($true) {
    $dataWS.countersamples | Format-Table Timestamp,@{Name='WorkingSet';Expression={($_.CookedValue/1KB)}},WorkingSetPeak,WorkingSetPrivate -Auto | findstr [:]
    $dataWSPe.countersamples | Format-Table Timestamp,WorkingSet,@{Name='WorkingSetPeak';Expression={($_.CookedValue/1KB)}},WorkingSetPrivate -Auto | findstr [:]
    $dataWSPr.countersamples | Format-Table Timestamp,WorkingSet,WorkingSetPeak,@{Name='WorkingSetPrivate';Expression={($_.CookedValue/1KB)}} -Auto | findstr [:]
    Start-Sleep -s $args[0]
}
```

and the result is like:

```
Timestamp           WorkingSet WorkingSetPeak WorkingSetPrivate
---------           ---------- -------------- -----------------
29/07/2016 18:41:12      10644                                 
29/07/2016 18:41:13                     10676                  
29/07/2016 18:41:14                                        3056
```

Is there a way to reduce to make output like this:

```
Timestamp           WorkingSet WorkingSetPeak WorkingSetPrivate
---------           ---------- -------------- -----------------
29/07/2016 18:41:12      10644          10676              3056
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collect all 3 counters at once (the parameter `-Counter` accepts a list of arguments), then split the result into separate [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
$ws     = '\Process(powershell)\Working Set'
$wsPeak = '\Process(powershell)\Working Set Peak'
$wsPriv = '\Process(powershell)\Working Set - Private'

Get-Counter -Counter $ws, $wsPeak, $wsPriv |
    Select-Object Timestamp,
        @{n='WorkingSet';e={$_.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue / 1KB}},
        @{n='WorkingSetPeak';e={$_.CounterSamples[1].CookedValue / 1KB}},
        @{n='WorkingSetPrivate';e={$_.CounterSamples[2].CookedValue / 1KB}}
```

The `CounterSamples` property is a list of [`PerformanceCounterSample`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.getcounter.performancecountersample%28v=vs.85%) objects that can be accessed individually by index.

If you don't want to rely on the results being returned in the order of the parameters passed to `Get-Counter` you can select them by their path, e.g. like this:

```
@{n='WorkingSetPeak';e={
  ($_.CounterSamples | Where-Object { $_.Path -like '*peak' }).CookedValue / 1KB
}}
```

For continuous sample collection add the parameters `-Continuous` and `-SampleInterval` to `Get-Counter`. A loop is not required.

```
$interval = 5  # seconds

Get-Counter -Counter $ws, $wsPeak, $wsPriv -Continuous -SampleInterval $interval |
    Select-Object ...
```